# How to load module specific css or js only to that specific page?

Tags: magento-2.1, custom, home

I want to add one css file to the home page but not to the contact us page.
I added like this on `default.xml` but it load on all pages.

```
<head>
  <css src="css/app.css"/>
</head>
```

How to do it?

Answer (score 1):

you have to add inside **cms_index_index.xml file** file to display only in homepage

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
      <css src="css/app.css"/>
       <link src="js/custom.js"/>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: Do I have to create cms_index_index.xml or I cam past the same in default.xml?

Comment: you have to create cms_index_index.xml file